# gradient-background buttons with bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I read the documentation, and there is a flag for enabling gradients on certain components: So maybe I am just stupid, but I don't see how this flag (**$enable-gradients: true;**) is supposed to do anything at all, I can find only a single reference to it in Bootstraps SASS files (.scss).

So how do i get some nice looking gradients in Bootstrap 4 without having to change all the classes like .btn-info? The presence of this flag seems to indicate that there is an elegant solution - if so I am just unable to find it..

Or maybe this variable was just created "in preparation" for themes, so they can build on top of it?

Comment: You'll need to compile a custom CSS. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251575/8918893

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, it seems like the properties where just not used in beta1.

They are used in beta2 though, see: 
https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2017/10/19/bootstrap-4-beta-2/