# How do you enable the new .bg-gradient- utilities?

Tags: bootstrap-4

https://blog.getbootstrap.com/ says

And when you use $enable-gradients, you’ll enable the new .bg-gradient- utilities (disabled by default) for use in navbars and more.

Q: How do I use $enable-gradients? Up until now I've just downloaded the bootstrap.css and .js files. But now apparently I have to compile them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You have to generate a custom CSS using Sass.

After [setting up the build tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45725946/8918893), you'll have to insert `$enable-gradients: true;` in your Sass file before the imports.

Then you can generate the custom CSS, and gradients should work!